# C++ .dll export for java jni

Tags: java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I want to use dll in my java program. I saw that we want to use __declspec(dllexport) to export my function in dll. Do we also want this while exporting using jniexport for java? I am using mingw compiler?

Comment: Take a look into that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454697/how-to-call-a-method-in-dll-in-a-java-program

Comment: I already saw it but it cannot answer my question.

Comment: Whether jniexport itself enough or i want to use __declspec(dllexport) to export my function into library

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to wrap your dll call and use the JNIEXPORT-macro from the native-interface in Java.

The  __declspec(dllexport) extension is a Microsoft-specific extension used in the VS-compiler to automatically export / import functions and classes/methods to dll's.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Can i use the following function? JNIExport int JNICall java_Main_add (int a,int b){} is it enough.

Comment: Yes, normally this shall be enought. And you need to load the wrapper package into your application.

Comment: Do you say dynamiclibrary as wraper package?

Comment: Yes, here is a tutorial how to do so: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html